# How can one thread determine if a different thread has crashed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

I have a background thread that is doing a bunch of work - loading the application.  The main thread is displaying progress on a UIProgressView.

The background thread is being spawned with performSelectorInBackground (though, I'm not wed to this method if a different approach makes this problem easier to solve)

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadAppInBackground) withObject:self];
```

On a couple occasions a bug has caused the background thread to crash (different bugs as the app evolves) which results in the progress bar stopping, but the user getting no clear indication that anything is wrong.

I'd like to detect this situation and fail more gracefully than simply hanging until the user gives up on waiting.

Because the duration of the load process can vary greatly, simply timing out isn't an ideal option.

What's the best way for the foreground thread to detect that the background thread has failed?  Since the foreground thread is busy dealing with the UI, would it require a second background thread to monitor the first?  That seems ugly.

Is there some thread-to-thread communication mechanism that could be used to "ping" the background process?  Better yet, a low level system mechanism of checking the status of other threads?

The debugger knows about all the threads that are running... and seems to know their status.  I'm wondering if there's a call available to my app to do the same.

Comment: How are you dispatching this background work (GCD, NSOperations, NSThreads)?  The answer depends on your implementation.

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadAppInBackground) withObject:self];

Comment: Timeout is the mostly used technique. Because it is impossible to determine whether the thread is running normally or in infinity loop (halting problem). So your foreground may check if the background task completed in 1 second (local I/O, or 15~60 sec for network I/O). Sorry I can only give a vague suggestion because you are asking a general problem.

Comment: Timeout doesn't work well in this case... the time the process takes varies quite a bit.  It's also network dependent, so, can also vary based on one's network speed.

Comment: You've swapped back and forth between describing threads and describing processes. I assume you mean threads here. And when you say "crash," do you mean throwing an ObjC exception, or do you mean generating a signal (such as a SEGV)? Generally anything that "crashes" one thread crashes the whole app (particularly on iOS). Are you somehow preventing the crash (and therefore entering an undefined program state?)

Comment: Yes, sorry... threads.  The crash is different each time.  The app is evolving and the load process is complicated.  When we find a bug we fix it, but, before then, I'd like to fail gracefully rather than quietly hang.  I don't think I'm doing anything to prevent a crash of the whole app.  What has happened in these cases is that the app just hangs... the foreground waiting for the background thread to finish - the progress bar standing still.

Comment: When you say "crashed", do you mean "stopped doing anything useful, stuck" or "terminated and is no longer in the process"? As Rob said, a real crash kills the entire application, so you couldn't detect it, but if it is one of these it can be detected. Which one it is determines what options are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no mechanism in objective c to check the status of a background thread directly.  Any of the answers provided are decent options... either timing out, or having the thread create some sort of evidence of its continued existence.

I was hoping for something a little more simple, reliable, and real-time.

I'm going to experiment with catching an exception in the thread and perhaps producing a notification like "BackgroundThreadException" that the foreground thread could listen for and react to.

Answer (score 1):

If the background task runs in some sort of regular cycle (eg, there's a big loop where much of the work gets done), it can set a flag every so often to indicate that it's still alive.

One way to do this is to have background thread store `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` somewhere, and, in your main thread, occasionally (perhaps on a timer) compare that to the current time.  If the difference is greater than some reasonable limit you can guess that the background thread has died.

Another way is to have the background thread simply set a Boolean, and have the main thread interrogate that and clear it on some regular basis.  If the Boolean doesn't get set again between main thread interrogations you can infer that it has died.

The first technique has the advantage that you can "tune" the "reasonable limit" to tolerate code (in either thread) that is somewhat irregular in it's timing.  The second approach generally requires timings that are more predictable.

Of course with either approach you want to somehow avoid "blowing the whistle" if the background thread has just finished up and you simply haven't recognized that yet.

Comment: Yes, plan B is to use a timeout, and we don't need to timeout the entire process.  Each individual step of the whole loading process can individually time out.  I was just hoping there was some call that, from the foreground, I could confidently verify that a different thread was still running - rather than verifying that it was running some arbitrary time ago by checking some side-effect.

Comment: @DaveOwens - The problem is that "thread death" is all too often hanging forever on a lock or getting caught in some sort of loop, vs simply ceasing to execute.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is to have an extra thread to check for life signs of the thread in question - a so called heartbeat thread. The heartbeat thread polls the thread by checking if it responds in a timely manner, if not, deems the thread dead and terminates it.

A simple heartbeat thread implementation would be to check a counter that is incremented regularly by the other thread, if the counter is not incremented within a certain time it is regarded as dead and then an appropriate action could be taken like restarting thread or killing app. Another more common way is if the hb thread sends messages to the thread and checks for a response with a timeout.

Comment: I suppose that would work as an absolute last resort, but, because the tasks involve downloading files of unknown sizes over networks of unknown speed and reliability, it's not clear how much time is TOO much time before giving up and assuming the background thread is dead.